# Issue with Deploying Forked Repo on Cloudflare Pages: Only Shows "Hello World"

Tags: github, deployment, repository, fork, cloudflare

I recently forked a repository from a project I contributed to, which serves as the codebase for a website. I'm not the owner of the original repository, but I forked it to deploy the website. However, upon deploying it using Cloudflare Pages, I'm encountering an unexpected issue.

The problem is that instead of displaying the actual website content, it's only showing "hello world." This is not the expected behavior, and I'm unsure why this is happening...

Here are the steps I've taken:

Forked the Repository:

- Successfully forked the repository from the original project.

Deployment on Cloudflare Pages:

- Configured the deployment settings on Cloudflare Pages.
- Selected the appropriate branch for deployment (e.g., main or master).
- Verified the folder containing the website's files.

Despite following these steps, the deployed site only shows "hello world" instead of the actual website content.

Could someone please assist me in troubleshooting this issue? Is there something specific I need to consider when deploying a forked repository on Cloudflare Pages that I might be missing?

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!